# How do the current FEM opensource libraries compare?

Tags: finite-element, numerics, hpc

Almost all FEM libraries are good enough, but I want to start with a FEM package and stick to it for some time. Instead of trying all of them, or going with what everyone else is using, I want to benefit from other user's experiences and know:

1. What are the pros and cons of the FEM libraries you have experience with? How do they compare to other libraries? What are they predominantly used for?
2. What is the philosophy and vision the developers have?

I already found this [link](https://github.com/kostyfisik/FEA-compare) which compares some of the FEM software packages, but I am looking for more input from others.

Other things you can think of when answering this question is, does the FEM package focus on and values:

- Generality: the ability to solve almost any problem by providing all the low level tools necessary such as special elements, geometries, special preconditioning, linear solvers...
- Efficiency and performance: Focusing on HPC and always trying to squeeze out every bit of computing power one can.
- Modernity?: Focusing on the use of state of the art mathematical techniques and hardware.
- Low level vs high level: Imagine having two libraries, where it might be easier to use library1 to set up a simple problem, but it can be less efficient than library2 when setting up more complicated problems. This is akin to generality i defined above.

Sorry for keeping things too general.

Comment: I think it might be hard to find someone who has experience from all of those or even more than two. I started with FEM around 10 years ago and I've used perhaps 4 of those listed in your link, some very briefly. Usually as soon as I encountered not easily solvable problems I went to the next code. Eventually I started doing research and ended up writing my own code because there was so many customization requirements and I didn't have the time or the mental resources to learn a huge codebase.

Comment: @knl do you think that maybe branching out from an already existing code might have been an equally valid path?

Comment: Yes, however, I think it would help to have some close colleague who is familiar with the codebase. Some relevant parts might take forever to find whereas someone familiar with the code knows where it is by heart.

Comment: Almost anyone here who can give you an informed answer -- including me -- likely depends on whatever finite element modeling package they've ended up choosing for their career in some way. For example, I'm paid from federal grants to develop a software package that is in turn built on Firedrake, and so I have a financial incentive to get other people to use Firedrake. Now I do think that it has some merits, otherwise I wouldn't use it. What I'm saying is that you're unlikely to get an objective answer. My advice is to try a couple and don't listen to us :D

Comment: I know. But still.

Comment: The tool to use depends on the problem you want to solve, particularly if you have to deal with nonlinearities and discontinuities.  For example, I have been looking for a tool that does contact between solid bodies reasonably well without the need to do extensive knob tweaking.  The best open-source tool I have found for that is Code-Aster, but it's nowhere close to what's commercially available.  For more generic use cases, Moose works well for me.  For developing from scratch, MoFEM has been good.  I have not found MFEM, dealII, etc. particularly useful.